# Java specific customer type

Tags: java, validation

I want to make a code where only the customers "R", "C", and "T" can make a subtotal.  Whenever I type another letter (i.e. "S", "L", "A", etc) I want the output to be invalid entry.  However, when I do enter a letter that is not R, C, or T, I am still asked to enter a subtotal.  Help as always.  Thanks.  Code is below.

======================

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ValidatedInvoiceApp
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c/t): ");
        String customerType = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter subtotal: ");
        double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

        // call the DiscountPercent method
        double discountPercent = getDiscountPercent(
        customerType,subtotal);

        // calculate the discount amount and total
        double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
        double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

        // format and display the results
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        System.out.println(
        "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
        "Discount amount: " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
        "Total: " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
        }
        }
        private static double getDiscountPercent(String customerType,double subtotal)
        {

        double discountPercent = 0;

            if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 100)
                discountPercent = 0;
            else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .1;
            else if (subtotal >= 250 && subtotal < 500)
                 discountPercent = .25;
            else
                discountPercent = .30;
            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            {
                discountPercent = .20;
            }
            else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
            {
            if (subtotal < 500)
                discountPercent = .40;
            else if (subtotal >= 500)
                discountPercent = .50;
            }
            else

                {
                    System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type.  Please Try Again. \n");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
        return discountPercent;
    }

    private static class sc {

        private static void nextLine() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public sc() {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't do any type of check about the input.

```
System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c/t): ");
String customerType = sc.next();
System.out.print("Enter subtotal: ");
double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();
```

You should use a do-while (or another thing if you want another behavior)

```
String customerType;
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c/t): ");
    customerType = sc.next();
}
while (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("c") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("t"));
```

With this code, until he write r, c or t he will be asked to insert again.

Anyway, you should consider the idea to use a char instead of String.

Answer (score 0):

You've to check for the customer type after you asked them to insert it. Your main method should look like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c/t): ");
        String customerType = sc.next();

        double subtotal = 0;
        if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("c") || customerType
                .equalsIgnoreCase("t")) {
            System.out.print("Enter subtotal: ");
            subtotal = sc.nextDouble();


            // call the DiscountPercent method
            double discountPercent = getDiscountPercent(
                    customerType, subtotal);

            // calculate the discount amount and total
            double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
            double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

            // format and display the results
            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
            System.out.println(
                    "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
                            "Discount amount: " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
                            "Total: " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type.  Please Try Again. \n");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```